# Spring-Integration UnableToRegisterMBeanException: InstanceAlreadyExistsException

Tags: spring-integration

I am getting InstanceAlreadyExistsException while trying to deploy in tomcat 8 in linux server the code with Spring Integration having 2 separate flows. I referred several forums and still not able to find a solution for this. But am not getting this exception while testing in my local tomcat 8 in windows platform. Any input is appreciated.

```
Stacktrace - 
2016-08-30 14:27:40 ERROR SpringApplication:838 - Application startup failed
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [getCities.channel#0] with key 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=getCities.channel#0'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=getCities.channel#0
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter.registerChannels(IntegrationMBeanExporter.java:675) ~[spring-integration-jmx-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(IntegrationMBeanExporter.java:271) ~[spring-integration-jmx-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:796) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:150) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:130) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5261) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816) [catalina.jar:8.0.35]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=getCities.channel#0
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:615) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

The configuration is given below -

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = JmxAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableMBeanExport(registration = RegistrationPolicy.IGNORE_EXISTING)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableAsync
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "foobar")
@PropertySource("classpath:environments/dev.properties")
@Import({SecurityConfig.class, IntegrationConfig.class})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    @Scope(BeanScopes.SINGLETON)
    public Logger getLogger() {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger("SampleService");
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggerAspect loggerAspect() {
        return new LoggerAspect(getLogger(), jsonMapper());
    }
}

@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan(basePackages = "fooBar")
@Import({FirstConfig.class, SecondConfig.class})
public class IntegrationConfig {

}

@MessagingGateway
public interface FirstGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "getCitiesChannel")
    CityModel[] getCities(Message<FirstPayload> message);
}

public class FirstConfig {
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel getCitiesChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sdsGetCities() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("input")
                .channel("getCitiesChannel")

                .handle(foobar)
                .get();
    }
}

@MessagingGateway
public interface SecondGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "getProductDetailsChannel")
    ProductModel getProductDetails(Message<SecondPayload> message);
}

public class SecondConfig {
    @Bean
    public MessageChannel getProductDetailsChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow getProductDetails() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("input")
                .channel("getProductDetailsChannel")
                .handle(foobar)
                .get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't show your `@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport`; if you are deploying 2 apps with similar flows, you need to put each app in a different domain `@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport(defaultDomain="foo")` and `@EnableIntegrationMBeanExport(defaultDomain="bar")`, so

```
org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=getCities.channel#0
```

becomes

```
foo:type=MessageChannel,name=getCities.channel#0
```

and

```
bar:type=MessageChannel,name=getCities.channel#0
```

If it's only one app (which it looks like) then it means the previous deployment didn't shut down properly.

Comment: Do you define the annotation on the FirstConfig or the IntegrationConfig?

Comment: Thanks Gary, I have my AppConfig class which holds the annotations (sorry I didnt share it earlier) . This class is common for both the integrations.

Comment: You can use a property placeholder, e.g. `defaultDomain = "${managed.domain}"` and use a different property value in each instance. We have a [test case that does that](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jmx/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/jmx/configuration/EnableMBeanExportTests.java#L123).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<context:mbean-export registration="replaceExisting"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using an abstract base class for my integration tests.

I added @DirtiesContext to my base class, so that the application context would be flushed between each test.